# Installed and compiled: tailwind classes not working on fresh install of laravel 6

Tags: laravel, webpack, tailwind-css

I've tried to install tailwind.css on a fresh install of Laravel 6. I've added some tailwind classes and it's just not working. No errors, no nothing.

**Install**

`npm install tailwindcss`

**resources/sass/app.scss**

```
@tailwind base;

@tailwind components;

@tailwind utilities;
```

**Generated a config file:**

`./node_modules/.bin/tailwind init`

**webpack.mix.js**

```
var tailwindcss = require('tailwindcss');

mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
  .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css')
  .options({
    processCssUrls: false,
    postCss: [ tailwindcss('tailwind.config.js') ],
});
```

**Compile**

`npm run dev`

I added some html:

```
<div class="rounded-lg p-6 bg-red-400">
  <img class="h-16 w-16 rounded-full mx-auto" src="https://picsum.photos/50/50">
  <div>
    <h2 class="text-lg text-red-400">Erin Lindford</h2>
    <div>Customer Support</div>
    <div>erinlindford@example.com</div>
    <div>(555) 765-4321</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm not getting any errors or anything. However, bootstrap is still installed, but I'm not sure that should matter too much.

Answer (score 6):

Rookie mistake:

`<link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">`

Was .scss and not css.